# Why after that I lost SSH connection during an installation I obtain this "Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open" error message?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, dpkg

I am not so into Linux and I have the following problem.

I was installing RedMine on a remote Ubuntu Server via SSH, following the official tutorial: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Ubuntu_step_by_step

The installation process is pretty simple but when I was performing this statment:

```
sudo apt-get install redmine redmine-mysql
```

I lost connection...so I come back into my server reconnecting to it...so I perform again this command but now I am obtaining this error message:

```
*** System restart required ***
Last login: Fri Nov 11 11:57:11 2016 from 91.253.121.46
root@Betrivius-VPS:~# apt-get install redmine redmine-mysql
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
root@Betrivius-VPS:~#
```

Reading online it seems that it means that the prvious installation process is not ended.

So I don't know if I can retrieve it in some way or abort it. When I log into my remote server appear the message **System restart required**. I don't know if this message is causated by this situation or not and I don't know if restart my server will solve this issue.

So what is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Since the first attempt to install did not conclude successfully, the lock-file (`/var/lib/dpkg/lock`), that avoids two processes manipulating the package structure of the system at the same time, is still there. (See here: http://askubuntu.com/a/102084/353824) Please do not just delete it without trying to solve this some other way. A couple of questions: Did you restart the system? Is there a reason not to? Is it usual that redmine requires the system to restart after installation (on unix-like systems packages should only do that if they constitute or replace some crucial system component)?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably go with something like `ps fauxww | less`, then start searching for `apt`, `dpkg` and especially `dialog` references. My guess is that before the ssh connection loss lead to your session child processes deletion, apt was asking you for some input, and is still waiting for it.

The system restart message is probably unrelated though. Or may be related to that same update, but not to the fact dpkg is locked.

Since you're installing, and not upgrading, I'ld say: just kill the processes hanging (if any). The dpkg lock file should go away shooting the right process, although make sure it's gone before going further. Then try running `apt-get install -f`. You might need to `apt-get install --reinstall redmine` & `redmine-mysql` (not familiar with redmine). You could want to `apt-get remove --purge redmine redmine-mysql`, then restart your installation from scratch.